# use string as regular text in code

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, integer, python-imaging-library

the code reads a txt file with numbers divided as

```
537, 487, 1115, 652\n
1265, 395, 1629, 693\n
```

the code reads the txt file and divides "\n" leaving a list like:

```
['537, 487, 1115, 652','1265,395,1629,693']
```

I need to use each string as a regular text in my code to crop an image using PIL
so I'd like to know if there is a way to get rid of the 'string' so in code it would look like that:

```
img2 = img.crop((537, 487, 1115, 652))
```

instead of:

```
img2 = img.crop(('537, 487, 1115, 652'))
```

the code looks like this:

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('file.txt')]

for i in range(0, len(lines)):

    img = Image.open("data\\image.jpg")
    img2 = img.crop((int(lines[i])))
    inimg = PIL.ImageOps.invert(img2)
    inimg.save("data\\orcropinverted.jpg")
```

*I know I could use a different approach and convert each number into an int but I'd like to know if it could be done that way.*

EDIT:

I figured something out with [re](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/regex.html) but it is not what I am looking for, anyway works...

```
import os, sys
import re
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('file.txt')]

for i in range(0, len(lines)):

    p = re.compile('\d+')
    sgline = p.findall(lines[i])

    img = Image.open("data\\image.jpg")
    img2 = img.crop((int(sgline[0]),int(sgline[1]),int(sgline[2]),int(sgline[3])))
    inimg = PIL.ImageOps.invert(img2)
    inimg.save("data\\orcropinverted.jpg")
```